# How to split and store data from dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have an Xl which as values mentioned below:

```
KF <-- Col Name
Values:
Ab122323,pop
89,HG903434
FG903434,99
```

I need to split the values using ',' and then count the length of each value and just store the value which as len = 8 and store it as a list --> into an excel

Comment: You've posted a lot of requirements without much effort shown.  Can you post your attempt?

Comment: Sorry for that, but i did try a lot of methods/steps which didn't result in what was required. I feel that it is totally unnecessary to add those here .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.Series.apply` with a generator expression. You will meet a `StopIteration` error if an item of length 8 cannot be found.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'KF': ['Ab122323,pop', '89,HG903434', 'FG903434,99']})

df['Filter'] = df['KF'].apply(lambda x: next(i for i in x.split(',') if len(i)==8))

df[['Filter']].to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)

print(df)

             KF    Filter
0  Ab122323,pop  Ab122323
1   89,HG903434  HG903434
2   FG903434,99  FG903434
```